# Prototype UITableViewCell initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Earlier I was creating custom cells without prototype, just custom class, register that class for reuse identifier with my UITableView and use like that.

In that case, I used: `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` and that worked great (except for UITableViewHeaderFooterView, they never knew their frame even though that method was called, frame was 0 0 0 0 - but that's not my question here).

Now I was creating some custom UITableViewCells using Interface Builder. Created their custom class, connected outlets from Interface Builder to my custom class and I'v noticed that `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` is being called and that's where I need to do my modifications.
BUT, I wasn't able. That's the only init method being called, but if I try to change font of my label there, it wont be changed. I also tried to round rect button but that is also not working (my button is also having frame 0 0 0 0 - not yet existing) in that method.

My question is, where should I modify things like font, background color of elements created using Prototype Cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` is the correct initializer.

Try this:

```
@implementation TESTCell

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:25.0f];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Other customizations (of own subviews) goes to:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [self.myButton setTitle:@"Hurray" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

It works fine. Of course, you have to set the identifier of the cell in your StoryBoard or Interface Builder file to the same identifier you use in your UITableViewController.

I use this piece of code in my UITableViewController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TESTCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"TEST";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Dobar dan. That's exactly what was I saying. If I try to customize something in that init method, it doesn't do the job. Imagine that you have a button in your prototype cell, created using Interface Builder. Button is connected via outlet to your custom class for that Prototype Cell. If you try to change background of that button in initWithCoder, nothing will happen. If you NSLog(@"%f", self.customButton.frame.size.width) you will get 0, even if it is not.

Only way to override this was to create my own function -(void)customizeCell, and call that after [dequeueReusable...] every time.

Comment: I see. You have to put this customization into awakeFromNib. I edited my answer above. Before awakeFromNib your custom subviews are not loaded yet.

Comment: Now that's the answer I was searching for. Thank you sir very much. Hvala!